# C- Determining start of a Bit-field using a Union

Tags: c, unions, bit-fields

For the example below, based on how bits.b.a is set to the value of bits.byte, does it mean it is the head of the bit-field? I know my machine is little-endian so doesn't it mean that a is the least significant bit or the most significant bit. Also is there a better way to determine the order of a bit-field through coding?

```
struct bit_fields {
    unsigned int a:4,
                 b:8,
                 c:20;
}
union myUnion { 
    bit_fields b;
    uint8_t byte;
}
int main(void) {
    union myUnion bits;
    bits.byte=1;
    printf("%u, %u, %u\n", bits.b.a, bits.b.b, bits.b.c);
    return 0;
}


Output: 
1, (random int less than 2^8), (random int less than 2^20)
```

Comment: _Never_ use unions like that. If you set a particular member of the union, you should use that member. Don't access other members of the union like that and expect predictable results, it's all UB.

Comment: Is there any other way to determine bit-field order? Also what is UB?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado you should add - if you want portable apps and do not know your compiler. Otherwise it is 100% DB.

Comment: do you know your compiler?

Comment: if gcc you do not have to worry, only change the uint8_t to uint32_t.

Comment: UB = Undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeterJ: Even if you knew you were compiling _now_ with a particular version of a compiler on a particular version of a platform, I'd say you still should not use this and expect particular behavior. Then you're unnecessarily tying yourself to a compiler which can change unexpectedly in the future. Then if you ever needed to port to a different platform or version, nobody wants to have to chase down a bug that was dependent on implementation defined behavior. This is not a lesson that a new person would want to learn about _after_ they made this mistake.

Comment: @PeterJ Do you mean GCC or something else? Also what do you mean by portable apps?

Comment: `.a` is the start of the bit field - there _may_ be padding.

Comment: To determine endian, `union { unsigned un; unsigned char uc[sizeof unsigned]; } .un =  { some_known_pattern; }`.  If the values of `uc[]` are as expected for LE, the endian is little, endian, etc.